# Question regarding the Cheese App on Ubuntu

Tags: camera, cheese

I recently was taking pictures using the Cheese app on my Ubuntu machine. I noticed that it randomly started taking pictures -- I did *not* click on the record or capture button. Why did it do this? Is my machine potentially hacked?

Thank you for your time and consideration,
Luke

Comment: Stuck button? Cat walking on the keyboard? Changed setting? (check Cheese Preferences --> Capture. Consider less-nefarious causes before jumping to "hacked".

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you have Burst mode selected instead of Photo. If by random, you mean every few seconds, I would check what tab is selected. On mine, I see Photo, Video, and Burst. If I select Burst, my camera will take pictures every few seconds until I click stop.

Comment: I didn't have burst selected and it just took one single camera shot. It did the countdown from 3. It kind of spooked me because I'm wondering if my machine is compromised. I'm guessing it's just most likely a bug.